# Let $u(x)$ - smooth function $u(x)\in C^{\infty }(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $u(x)$ - smooth function $u(x)\in C^{\infty }(\mathbb{R})$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|u(x)|^2 (\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2})dx< \infty$.

Proof that  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 u(x) }{\mathrm{d} x^2}|^2 (\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2})dx< \infty$

---

I tried to use integration by parts - $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|u(x)|^2ch(x)dx=u^2(x)sh(x)|_{-\infty}^{\infty}-2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|u(x)u'(x)|sh(x)dx$

But what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the behavior at $\pm \infty$ separately.
Reduce to the problem: the behavior of $|u(x)|^2 e^{x}$ vs $|u''(x)|^2 e^x$.  But we can clearly see counterexamples: $u^2 e^x$ integrable, but $(u'')^2 e^x$ is not, for instance take $u(x) =e^{-x} \sin e^x$.

Maybe your problem is in the opposite direction?  This somehow makes sense, since if $\frac{u''(x)}{e^x} \to \alpha$, then $\frac{u(x)}{e^x} \to \alpha$ (l'Hospital), but not conversely.